# Illegal characters in path vs2017 loop output window

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, visual-studio-2017

I have VS2017 installed and I am connecting to VSTS online.

The Output window (Show output from Source Control - Team Foundation) is filling up with `Illegal characters in path.` output.

[image: Problem]

I don't know why.  I have seen this appear a few times on other projects but never investigated why.  Today I had a chance to catch the problem.

The structure of the project is as follows:

```
FullStackAspNetCore\.editorconfig
FullStackAspNetCore\database
FullStackAspNetCore\docs
FullStackAspNetCore\Files.txt
FullStackAspNetCore\FullStackAspNetCore.sln
FullStackAspNetCore\FullStackAspNetCore.vssscc
FullStackAspNetCore\src
FullStackAspNetCore\test
FullStackAspNetCore\.vs\config
FullStackAspNetCore\.vs\FullStackAspNetCore
FullStackAspNetCore\.vs\config\applicationhost.config
FullStackAspNetCore\.vs\FullStackAspNetCore\v15
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB.dbmdl
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB.sqlproj
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB.sqlproj.user
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB.sqlproj.vspscc
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\bin
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\dbo
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\Import Schema Logs
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\obj
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\scripts
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\bin\Debug
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\bin\Release
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\bin\Debug\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB.dacpac
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\bin\Debug\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB.dll
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\bin\Debug\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB.pdb
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\dbo\Tables
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\dbo\Tables\ApplicationRoles.sql
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\dbo\Tables\ApplicationUsers.sql
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\dbo\Tables\__EFMigrationsHistory.sql
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\Import Schema Logs\Acme.FullStack.SqlSe_20170629095103.log
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\obj\Debug
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\obj\Debug\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB.dll
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\obj\Debug\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB.pdb
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\obj\Debug\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB.sqlproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\scripts\dev
FullStackAspNetCore\database\Acme.FullStack.SqlServerDB\scripts\dev\insert dev data.sql
FullStackAspNetCore\docs\Entity Framework.md
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF.csproj
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF.csproj.vspscc
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\appsettings.json
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\bin
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\Contexts
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\Migrations
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\obj
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\bin\Debug
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF.deps.json
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF.dll
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF.pdb
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model.dll
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model.pdb
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\Contexts\ApplicationDbContext.cs
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\Contexts\AuthenticationDbContext.cs
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\Contexts\AuthenticationDbContextFactory.cs
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\Migrations\20170629093101_InitialCreate.cs
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\Migrations\20170629093101_InitialCreate.Designer.cs
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\Migrations\AuthenticationDbContextModelSnapshot.cs
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\obj\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF.csproj.nuget.g.props
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\obj\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF.csproj.nuget.g.targets
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\obj\Debug
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\obj\project.assets.json
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF.AssemblyInfo.cs
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF.dll
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF.pdb
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\CoreCompileInputs.cache
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.EF\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model.csproj
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model.csproj.vspscc
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\Authentication
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\bin
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\obj
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\Authentication\ApplicationRole.cs
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\Authentication\ApplicationUser.cs
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\bin\Debug
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model.deps.json
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model.dll
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model.pdb
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\obj\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model.csproj.nuget.g.props
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\obj\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model.csproj.nuget.g.targets
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\obj\Debug
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\obj\project.assets.json
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model.AssemblyInfo.cs
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model.dll
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model.pdb
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\CoreCompileInputs.cache
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Data.Model\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\Acme.FullStack.Web.csproj
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\Acme.FullStack.Web.csproj.vspscc
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\bin
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\obj
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\Program.cs
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\Properties
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\Startup.cs
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\wwwroot
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\bin\Debug
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Web.deps.json
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Web.dll
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Web.pdb
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Web.runtimeconfig.dev.json
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Web.runtimeconfig.json
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\obj\Acme.FullStack.Web.csproj.nuget.g.props
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\obj\Acme.FullStack.Web.csproj.nuget.g.targets
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\obj\Debug
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\obj\project.assets.json
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Web.AssemblyInfo.cs
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Web.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Web.csprojResolveAssemblyReference.cache
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Web.dll
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\Acme.FullStack.Web.pdb
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\CoreCompileInputs.cache
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\obj\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs
FullStackAspNetCore\src\Acme.FullStack.Web\Properties\launchSettings.json
```

Does anyone know where to look to start diagnosing this?

Comment: Did your files are in use? According to this similar question with the same error info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157816/build-error-while-syncing-the-git-repo-illegal-characters-in-path  It's probably a  "ressource in use" error.

Answer (score 1):

Quick & Dirty solution:
Focus on the output window, hit 'Esc'.

Other have pointed that disabling the "Source Control - Team Foundation" menu bar solves the issue.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/166821/illegal-characters-in-path-being-emitted-continuou.html